# How to read html and loop for insert to MySQL in realtime?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, thread-safety

I read html table and put to MySQL with this code

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://xxx")
bt = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") 
alltable = bt.find_all('table')

def read_data(last_id):

    lst_df = pd.read_html(str(alltable))

    #Change list of daframe to one dataframe
    df = pd.concat(lst_df)


    l_id = last_id+1    
    res = df.loc[df.ID ==l_id]
    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

    if not res.empty:

        number = res['number'].item()
        user = res['User'].item()

        qt = check_user(user)

        if not number > qt:

            r = q - p

            sql = "UPDATE user SET p = %s WHERE user = %s"
            val = (r, user)
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            mydb.commit()

            print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected")

        #Insert Log
        sql = "INSERT INTO log (id, user, number, l_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,)"
        val = [(None, user, number , l_id)]

        mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

        mydb.commit()

        print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.") 

        mycursor.close()
```

I use while loop for run function with this code.

```
while True:
    last_id = get_last_id_db()
    read_data(last_id)
```

It call function one time only. I update html table but MySQL not update. when I update table MySQL should automatical update because while ture still running.

It have no problem when I click run button 1 time. but I want to automatic check html. So, I use while true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This should be inside `read_data()` function, so you fetch the latest status of the web rather than only once in the beginning

   ```
   html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://xxx")
   bt = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") 
   alltable = bt.find_all('table')
   ```
2. Do you always pass in the same `last_id` to `read_data()`?
3. (Highly recommended) You should have some sort of `sleep()` mechanism in the loop to just fetch the data every few seconds/ minutes.